# Load webview content via gprs edge

Tags: android, webview

I'm loading a "lobby url" which has a few html5 based games via a webview in Android.  If I'm connected via wi-fi everything works fine, however if I'm connected via my cellular provider it loads a game about a quarter then it reloads my lobby, I also cannot login if I'm not on wi-fi either. Here are the settings I use.

```
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "Game Title", "Loading...");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out why, it's because my isp had blocked the domain